# Examples on Zend_Rest_Controller Unit Testing

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-rest, restful-architecture

I have found a bunch of examples how to unit test Zend_Controller, but I'm looking for examples on Zend_Rest_Controller Unit Testing. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't that a controller as well? What makes it so different to standard controllers that you can not use the standard testing for controllers?

Comment: Methods PUT and DELETE -- Please refer to [Rest on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)

Comment: I know what rest is. What's the problem in testing PUT and DELETE?

Comment: Well, try it out by yourself and let me know if you succeed. I didn't place the question just in vain or just for fun ;)

Comment: I assume so, point in case is just that you should make your problem a bit more specific otherwise I can only say: What's your problem? What does not work? Which error are you getting? What makes you think that it *should* work?

Comment: You're right, it not that different from regular Zend_Controller. It was my mistake! I thought to share some of my code, just in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically your question is how to emulate calling `PUT` and `DELETE` in your controller tests?
Since this apparently doesn't work:

```
$this->request->setMethod('PUT');
```

You can access both these actions with plain `HTTP POST` by providing `_method` parameter.

So to call `PUT`:

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST');
$this->dispatch('articles/123?_method=put');
```

To call `DELETE`:

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST');
$this->dispatch('articles/123?_method=delete');
```

More reading on how to deal with RESTful routing here - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Sample class to test a controller
 */
class ArticleControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

    public $bootstrap;

    public function setUp()
    {
        // When bootstrap is called it will run function 'appBootstrap'
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
    {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        $this->application->bootstrap();
        $bootstrap = $this->application->getBootstrap();
        $front = $bootstrap->getResource('FrontController');
        $front->setParam('bootstrap', $bootstrap);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->resetInstance();
        $this->resetRequest();
        $this->resetResponse();
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testIndexAction()
    {
        $testCases = array(
            '/article/',
            '/article/id/123/',
            '/article/authorId/777/limit/5/',
            '/article/commentId/999/startDate/2011-06-01/endDate/2011-06-01/',
        );

        foreach ($testCases as $url) {
            $this->request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');
            $this->dispatch($url);

            $this->assertResponseCode(200);
            $this->assertModule('default');
            $this->assertController('article');
            $this->assertAction('get');

            $body = json_decode($this->response->getBody(), true);
            $this->assertNotEmpty($body);
            ...

            $this->resetRequest();
            $this->resetResponse();
        }
    }

    public function testGetAction()
    {
        // Same as $this->testIndexAction()
    }

    public function testPostAction()
    {
        // Similar to $this->testIndexAction()
        // Add $this->request->setMethod('POST'); before dispatch
        // Change $this->assertResponseCode(200); to 201 as REST requires
    }

    public function testPutAction()
    {
        // Similar to $this->testIndexAction()
        // Add $this->request->setMethod('PUT'); before dispatch
    }

    public function testDeleteAction()
    {
        // Similar to $this->testIndexAction()
        // Add $this->request->setMethod('DELETE'); before dispatch
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is a good resource on how to create REST API in the first place: http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework